# RSpec testing destroy controller action throws an error: ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am writing tests for my controller and I get keep getting the error `ActionView::MissingTemplate`. I have looked at related questions asked before but I can't seem to get it working with my scenario.

Here is my controller code:

```
def confirm_destroy
  render :layout => 'overlay'
end

def destroy
  @role.destroy
end
```

And here is the test I have written:

```
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
  let!(:role) { create(:role, user: current_user) }
  let(:params) { {id: role.id, format: :json} }

  it 'performs a delete' do
    expect { delete :destroy, params }.to change { Role.count }.by(-1)
  end
end
```

when I run the test I get the error:

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template company/settings/roles/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :slim]}. Searched in:
     * "/my_app/app/views"
     * "/usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.5.0/app/views"
```

Any idea why this is so? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When controller `destroy` action is finished, Rails tries to render a default template (view) and it's not defined, meaning you don't have file `my_app/app/views/company/settings/roles/destroy.json`.

You have several options to fix it:

1. Define `my_app/app/views/company/settings/roles/destroy.json` and it will be rendered (not advised for JSON).
2. Redirect to other action, e.g. `index` (again, not advised for JSON).
3. Render json or explicitly render nothing (see below)

--

```
# render nothing:
def destroy
  @role.destroy
  head :ok
end

# render json:
# render nothing:
def destroy
  @role.destroy
  render json: { deleted: true }, status: :no_content
end
```

Comment: Is there no way this can be tested out without changing the controller code?

Comment: I'd say your test detected a bug in the controller, so you should fix it.